# LSP hover text markdown links from C# not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, omnisharp, language-server-protocol

I'm working on a VSCode extension with an LSP (implemented in C#/Omnisharp). I've implemented my language hover provider in the LSP and it's working fine. However, I want to add a clickable [vscode] command link to the hover. I've done this before using markdown in extension Typescript code like [Label](command:some-command), but it's not working from the LSP C# code. From there it just displays flat text as Label, but not as a clickable URI link. If the Uri is a regular https link it works, but not if it's a vscode Uri. Anyone know the magic to enable vscode command links in markdown from LSP C# code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the markdown content `isTrusted` flag to get links to work. For a language extension server you need edit the `LanguageClientOptions` in the client's typescript file.

```
let clientOptions: LanguageClientOptions = {
    markdown: {
        isTrusted: true,
    },
}

let client = new LanguageClient('myClient', 'My Client', serverOptions, clientOptions);
```

It's described on their GitHub in this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node/issues/503)